# What is the best Python GUI module to do a project with multiple screens in one window in?

Tags: python, user-interface, module, tkinter

I'm not exactly sure to describe it so here is a basic storyboard of what I would like to do using Python: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dciMH.jpg

I'm quite new to GUI programming so I'm unsure which Python module is best for this. I've had a little look at Tkinter. How I would get the screen to change to the second image after the next button is pressed without opening a new window in Tkinter?

Secondly, what are some other GUI Python modules that you would recommend for this sort of project I'm doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tkinter is a perfectly fine toolkit to lean on, as are other toolkits. The advantage tkinter has is that you probably already have it installed. Plus, it is very simple to use, and very powerful.

To answer your question on how to get the screen to change: tkinter uses geometry managers named `pack` and `grid` (and to a much lesser extent, `place`) to layout your widgets in a window. These geometry managers have the feature that they can be asked to remove a window, making it invisible.

You can, for instance, create each "page" as a `Frame` with other widgets inside. To switch pages, call `pack_ forget` or `grid_forget` to hide the current page, then `pack` or `grid` to show the new page. This is a very common and useful technique. `grid_remove` has an added feature in that it remembers the options that were used to originally display the window, makinging it a little easier to toggle it between being visible and hidden.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining this to me! It was exactly what I was looking for as you have told me the methods to call.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.wxpython.org/

I recommand wxpython.

if it's simple, do within wxpython.

Comment: I'm not downvoting because I dislike wxPython, I'm downvoting because of the statement "if it's simple, do within wxpython". That seems like bad advice to me. If it's simple, why not use the toolkit that is part of a standard python installation? Could you explain your reasoning?

Comment: @BryanOakley I am really sorry for that I state so simply. Actually, I might not have more experience than you at python. But, my thinking is that. AnonUser who ask this question is quite new on GUI programming. So, i recommand wxpython. cause it doesn't need to install and practice with new tools. I don't say whether tkinter is bad or not. I say wxpython is easier than tkinter for someone who is n't familiar with GUI programming.

Answer (score 0):

I did that in pygtk by using a tabbed widget with hidden tabs.
You can design it in glade and later automate switching between tabs in your code.

Nowadays I would probably go with QT for a new project, though I haven't yet.